# get variable comprehensive to other function

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have the following:

```
if ($firstBG.hasClass("inview")) {
    $(window).resize(function () {
        var height = $(window).height();
        var getfactor1 = 680 / 697;
        var posval1 = height * getfactor1;
        console.log(posval1);
    });

    $firstBG.css({
        'backgroundPosition': posval1)
    });
}
```

But it does not get the value of `posval1` in the background function. What am I doing wrong? I want to get the value of `posval1` in the `if inview` and on resize function!

Thanks.

Comment: You are using `posval1` outside the scope where it is declared.

Comment: and thats the question, how can i get a new value from (window).resize and put it in firstBG.css();

Comment: Why don't move it inside `(window).resize` handler?

Comment: If you want the `.css` code to happen when the `resize` event occurs, then you need to put it in the `resize` habndler instead of after it. If it wasn't clear to you that the code was placed *after* the handler, then I'd guess you were suffering the ramifications of not using consistent indentation in your code.

Comment: Would declaring `posval1` outside the handler help? It wouldn't be initialised before the handler is fired, but it should be easy to fix ;-)

Comment: thank you guys for your help. what i exactly need is, the "posval1" should be a new value depending on the browser height which is read by a factor and this factor multiplied with the current browser height. hope you get my point?

Comment: i just need to fire this `var height = $(window).height();
        var getfactor1 = 680 / 697;
        var posval1 = height * getfactor1;`and put the current value in the `in inview`function

Answer (score 2):

You will need to set the css property from the resize handler. If you want to initialize it, you just could trigger it:

```
if($firstBG.hasClass("inview")){
    $(window).resize(function() {        
        var height = $(window).height();
        var getfactor1 = 680/697;
        var posval1 = height*getfactor1;
        console.log(posval1);
        $firstBG.css({'backgroundPosition': posval1)});
    }).resize();
```